# How to open folder from ngide?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ubuntu-16.04

I installed **ngide** using this commands.

```
 sudo npm install -g angular-ide
 ngide install ~/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-ide
```

But I don't know how to open my angular2 project folder in ngide. Please tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either

File -> Open Projects from File system 
Then in the dialog box click "Directory..." to find your directory and select and do finish.

or 
File -> import
in the dialog box expand general and select "projects from Folder or Archive" and click "Next>" .  this will bring the same dialog box to choose your folder .